# Find Highlighted Row in Tab from Query

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a company form that list their basic info with a subform tab that list more company info like contacts, parts and orders. I use a tab control where each tab has a table with basic info about each that is populated from a query. I am trying to open another form that has detailed information about the user highlighted row in the query, but cannot figure out how to read which row is selected.

The form is called Customer, the tab form is called tabDetails, the parts tab is caled tabParts and the query that lists all the parts for the company is called qryPartsList.

This is what I thought would work.

```
ID = Me!tabDetails!tabParts!qryPartsList!CurrentRecord![ID]
```

Comment: Doesn't work is great decription;) Rest of Code? Read [ask]!

Answer (score 1):

The table is normally held in a subform control of the main form, and the ID will be that of the current record, so try:

```vb
ID = Me!qryPartsList.Form![ID].Value
```

Answer (score 0):

My problem was I kept trying to call the query and not the object for the query. The tab's child object is what I needed to call. I named it 'Part_Info' and then Gustav's answer worked for me.

```
ID = Me!Part_Info.Form![ID].Value
```

Thanks!